# Why is split() function failing on only one condition but not another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, split

### Context

I'm converting a create-react-app app to nextjs. Most of my work is ensuring existing components work for SSR.

I have one component that is throwing a build error of:

```
Error: text.split is not a function
```

For the final condition of this function:

```
function createRender(text, type, size, paragraphs, inline, nogap, url) {

    let renderObj;
    if (text) {
        // if text is an array, return a string of the array
        if (text instanceof Array) {
            text = text.join('');
        }
        if (type === "title") {
            renderObj = <h2>{text}</h2>
        } else if (paragraphs === true) {
            renderObj = text.split('\n').map((paragraph, index) => {
                if (paragraph !== "") {
                    return  <p>{paragraph}</p>
                }
            })
        } else {
            renderObj = text.split('\n').map((paragraph, index) => {
                if (paragraph !== "") {
                    return  <p >{paragraph}</p>
                }
            })
        }
    }

    return renderObj
}
```

### Question

This split request (as far as I can see) is identical to that in the condition preceding it. Which doesn't throw an error.

This isn't an error occuring at runtime when something that isn't a string has been passed. This is a build error.

What am I missing that might be causing text in this one condition to throw this error? In my previous experience with javascript, I'd only get an error when running and a variable that wasn't a string had an attempted split. Here, a variable hasn't even been sent yet.

Also, why isn't it causing an error in the condition above it, with the exact same code? If I remove the final 'else' condition, I don't get the error.

### Caveats

Ignore the logic in the conditions, I've removed some fluff to make this reproducible in its smallest form.

I'm using nextjs 13 and its app folder. I'm brand new to nextjs and saw this is an experimental features so I'm unsure if something exterior from this function is causing the issue.

---

#### Update 1

I've found that the error isn't thrown if I add a defined condition to the final **else**. As in, if I replace:

```
} else {
    renderObj = text.split('\n').map((paragraph, index) => {
        if (paragraph !== "") {
            return  <p >{paragraph}</p>
        }
    })
}
```

with

```
} else (any variable === anything) {
    renderObj = text.split('\n').map((paragraph, index) => {
        if (paragraph !== "") {
            return  <p >{paragraph}</p>
        }
    })
}
```

The condition definition is arbitrary. I can put `size === 'melon'` and it no longer throws an error.

Comment: Yes, the code block where `split` was called is identical, but is the `text` variable still a string type regardless of whether the `paragraphs` variable is true or false? Even with the information provided above, determining the source of the problem remains difficult. I believed NextJS is not the problem here; it's the data or content that you pass to the `createRender` function. Also note that the SSR page will execute the `createRender` function code even during build time to create the pre-rendered page. So I advised check or log first the value of `text` when `paragraphs` is false.

Comment: Thanks, good to have some starting points for where to look. What I don't understand is, text is just a stated variable. It doesn't have a type defined yet and - as it has to be passed a variable when building - how can it determine what text is yet? I tried defining text as string in propTypes

Comment: I believe I missed that the build process with SSR is actually going to pass real variables to this function, whereas I'm used to this only happening at runtime. I think I've been looking at this from the wrong perspective, of what could potentially crash the function vs what real variables actually are crashing it. Thanks for the steer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was too used to client-side-rendering and was still using the perspective that functions and variables only throw errors when building if there's bad code.

Whereas as this function is built for SSR, it's being passed actual real variables and is throwing an error in the same veign as I would have been familiar with during runtime on CSR.

So the problem was catching a bad variable that was meant to be a string but wasn't.